# DataGridView ImageColumn Handle "Enter" key to perform Click

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

How to fire `Click` event of `DataGridViewImageColumn` when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Currently when I press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on  `DataGridViewImageColumn` it moves to next cell.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: you mean all that images... add edit..... or just row selected, then move to another image?

Comment: On Add Image click (Key board Enter Key) , it should behave as a mouse click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the code that you want to run in `CellContentClick` in a method and then on both `CellContentClick` and `KeyDown` call that method.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex== 3)
        DoSomething(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex);
}

public void DoSomething(int row, int column)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Cell({0},{1}) Clicked", row, column));
}

private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = this.dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
    if (cell != null && e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter &&
        cell.RowIndex >= 0 && cell.ColumnIndex == 3)
    {
        DoSomething(cell.RowIndex, cell.ColumnIndex);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention `e.ColumnIndex== 3` is to check if the click in on column at index 3.